# How to use setTimeout without using setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Is there a way to use `setTimeout` without using `setTimeout` inbuilt function?

I don't want to use `setInterval` or `clearInterval` either or `window.use`. I have gone through multiple blogs, but all those use `window`, `setInterval` or `clearInterval`.

For example, the below code works, but I dont want to have window.

```
const setTimeouts = [];
function customSetTimeout(cb, interval) {
  const now = window.performance.now();
  const index = setTimeouts.length;
  setTimeouts[index] = () => {
    cb();
  };
  setTimeouts[index].active = true;
  const handleMessage = (evt) => {
    if (evt.data === index) {
      if (window.performance.now() - now >= interval) {
        window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
        if (setTimeouts[index].active) {
          setTimeouts[index]();
        }
      } else {
        window.postMessage(index, '*');
      }
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
  window.postMessage(index, '*');
  return index;
}

const setIntervals = [];
function customSetInterval(cb, interval) {
  const intervalId = setIntervals.length;
  setIntervals[intervalId] = function () {
    if (setIntervals[intervalId].active) {
      cb();
      customSetTimeout(setIntervals[intervalId], interval);
    }
  };
  setIntervals[intervalId].active = true;
  customSetTimeout(setIntervals[intervalId], interval);
  return intervalId;
}

function customClearInterval(intervalId) {
  if (setIntervals[intervalId]) {
    setIntervals[intervalId].active = false;
  }
}

console.log("1");
customSetTimeout(function() {
  console.log('3s');
}, 3000);
console.log("2");
```

=======================================

Alternate solution:
But here, again i dont want to use clearInterval and setInterval

```
var setMyTimeOut = function(foo,timeOut){
 console.log('inside time out');
    var timer;
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var blah=()=>{

      if (new Date().getTime() >= currentTime + timeOut) {
      console.log('clear interval if');
        clearInterval(timer);
        foo()
      }
       console.log('clear interval else');
  }
  timer= setInterval(blah, 100);
}
console.log("1");
setMyTimeOut(function() {
  console.log('3s');
}, 3000);
console.log("2");
```

Is there way to achieve the same but without the use setInterval and clearInterval?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the use case?

Comment: I am working on a MFP adapter wherein setTimeout is not supported. Hence I want to create a custome setTimeout function.Not only setTimeout, window. is also not supported.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MFP, but do any of the following work? `global.setTimeout || globalThis.setTimeout || self.setTimeout || window.setTimeout`

Comment: nope, all these inbuilt javascript functions doesnt work. Thats why i have to create my own custom function.

Answer (score 3):

I use here the `requestAnimationFrame` with `performance.now()`.

Its not super exact (well setTimeout neither), but it do the work.

```js
function sleep(delay, cb) {
     function check(time, delay) {
        if(time >= delay) {
           cb("done");
           return;
        }
        time = performance.now();
        requestAnimationFrame(check.bind(null, time,delay))
     }
     check(performance.now(), delay + performance.now());
}



sleep(4000, ()=> {
   console.log("sleep done");
})

console.log("i do not block the main thread");
```

Comment: I dont want to use Promise or any inbuilt async functions as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Nancy so your environment doesnt even have promises?

Comment: No, it doesnt support Promises ,setTimeout, async,  await

Comment: @Nancy here, i have done it oldschool with an callback function

Comment: @Nancy i guess this wont work either because `performance` belongs to the window object

Comment: @Ifaruki There's also `Date.now()`, if you have access to `Date`. Though I'd be pretty surprised if you have access to `requestAnimationFrame` either

Comment: @Nancy well i dont know how to do this without blocking the main thread. i cannot use anything that would help me like window object, setTimeout, promises... i guess you dont have access to web workers aswell that would be an solution otherwise i have no plan

Comment: As @Ifaruki mentioned, I have access to Date.now(), but I dont have access to requestAnimationFrame. Is there any alternative approach to requestAnimationFrame usage

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop which checks a set time against the current time:

```js
const startTime = new Date().getTime() + 3000;
let currentTime = new Date().getTime();

function customTimeout() {
  while (startTime > currentTime) {
    currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  }
  
  return console.log('3 Seconds')
};

customTimeout();
```

Comment: This blocks the main thread. Very different from `setTimeout`

Comment: I want the customTimeout function to be a callback, the code after customTimeout() should keep on executing untill the customTimeout() finishes its execution.
console.log("Executed after 1 seconds");
customTimeout();
console.log("Executed after 3 seconds");   // this has to be executed before customTimeout()

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done with the restrictions you have